# Why does Colab not find the parent directory for relative imports?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, relative-import

I have a python file that I tested locally using VS-Code and the shell. The file contains relative imports and worked as intended on my local machine.

After uploading the associated files to Colab I did the following:

```
py_file_location = '/content/gdrive/content/etc'
os.chdir(py_file_location)

# to verify whether I got the correct path
!python3
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
output: '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/content/etc'
```

However, when I run the file I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Why is that? Using the same file system and similar shell commands the file worked locally.

Comment: You will need to show the code you're trying to run. It clearly has a misplaced relative import.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was to turn my relative paths into static ones, so instead of using:

```
directory = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.append(str(directory.parent))
sys.path.append(str(directory.parent.parent.parent))
__package__ = directory.name
```

I needed to make the path static by using resolve():

```
directory = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent
sys.path.append(str(directory.parent))
sys.path.append(str(directory.parent.parent.parent))
__package__ = directory.name
```

It is however still not fully clear to me why this is required when running on Colab but not when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below:

1. Consolidate all your files in one directory on your local machine.
2. Make sure that all the file paths in your code are relative to this directory.
3. Upload the entire directory to Google Colab.
4. Before running your script in Colab, change the current working directory to the newly uploaded directory.

You can achieve this by executing the following code snippet in the first cell in your Colab Notebook:

```
%cd /content/your_directory_name
```

Then all your files will be in a single directory, and your code will be able to access them using relative paths.